# Equinox launcher

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, launcher

What is the big difference between launching Equinox via `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar` and using org.eclipse.equinox.launcher (basically, `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar`)?

I suppose that org.eclipse.equinox.launcher provides some added value, but what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

equinox.launcher processes special arguments before starting osgi framework. If you want to know more, the best way is reading the source code of equinox.launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Well. The class which is used by both methods to start equinox framework is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter`. It's located in the `org.eclipse.osgi_version.jar`.

They use the same class. So, basically, they are the same.

However, the equinox.launcher provides more additional features. For example, a default splash banner, checking security and installation path, some more debug information etc.

The equinox.launcher is intended to be used as an application launcher of the framework/application.

If you directly run the `org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar` file by invoking `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar`. It actually calls the main method in the `EclipseStarter` class.

This class is intended to be used as a programmable starter of the framework. That means you should use this class if you want to start the equinox framework from your code.

Generally speaking, you should use equinox.launcher for launching your OSGi application from command line or other similar means.

Hope this helps.